# Using Boost.Asio is there any equivalent of "read_until" for datagram sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm working on a simple UDP broadcast service using the boost Asio library in cpp.
By using TCP sockets (`basic_stream_socket<tcp>`) I can employ the method `boost::asio::read_until(...)` to read data from the socket until the delimiter is found, but for datagram sockets (such as a UDP socket) the same method is not available, so I wanted to ask if there's a similar method to achieve the same result (read data until delimiter found) on a UDP socket (connected to local endpoint obviously)?

Instead, is it possible to create a `basic_stream_socket<udp>` ? What difference would there be with a `basic_datagram_socket<udp>`? Would it still work for normal send/receive operations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking you only get one chance to read a `UDP` datagram (ignoring flags such as `MSG_PEEK` etc.): you can't read part of it and then go back and read the rest.  Can you clarify why you need this?  As it is it sounds like an xy-problem.

Comment: Merely, I wanted to replicate the functionality I used with a tcp socket in a udp socket: to send messages between tcp sockets I used a special delimiter so that every socket could know the separation between the messages (and use "read_until" to read them separately). I needed a similar option with UDP sockets, because otherwise I'd have to rely on message size, but I'd have to change my whole system..

Comment: Why don't you just send one message per datagram and forget about the separator?